# Jmeter: Distributed Testing with client certificates

Tags: jmeter, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, distributed-testing

We set up Jmeter for performance testing over HTTPS with client certificates (via SSL Manager). It works like a charm if we run it from GUI. But, if we start distributed testing we get a bad certificate error.

How to pass the certificates & password to the slaves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the certificates using [Java SSL System Properties](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_MQ_Enterprise/7.1/html/Security_Guide/files/SSL-SysProps.html)

I.e. add the following lines to *system.properties* file on each remote slave machine:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=certificate.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=secr3t
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12
```

- amend above values to match your settings
- JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up.

You can also pass the values via `-D` command-line arguments like:

```
jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=certificate.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=secr3t -s ...
```

See [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) article for more detailed explanation.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot for your help!